# Is my jQuery syntax wrong here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I am learning jQuery and I'm finding that this code is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(
    /* Navigtion Stuff */
      function(){
        $('.menu ul').hover(
          function(){
            $(this).parent().addClass("active");
          },
          function(){
            $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
          }
        )
      },
      function(){
        $(".menu").parents("li").addClass("active");
      }
    );
</script>
```

The first function does what it is supposed to. The second function does not. Is my syntax bad? If not, then I have a feeling that my code is conflicting with some other Javascript on the page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes! Alright guys, you just helped me tremendously. Thank you!

Comment: JR, if you were helped you should accept an answer so that the work invested by the others isn't in vain.

Answer (score 4):

you have a little confusion with the brackets

```
 $(document).ready(
/* Navigtion Stuff */
  function(){
    $('.menu ul').hover(
      function(){
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
      },
      function(){
        $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
      }
    );
    $(".menu").parents("li").addClass("active");
  }
);
```

is better.

Answer (score 3):

The ready function only takes one parameter. You are trying to pass two functions.

function 1 :

```
function(){
    $('.menu ul').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        },
        function(){
            $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
        }
    )
}
```

function 2:

```
function(){
    $(".menu").parents("li").addClass("active");
}
```

To bind the hover event to `$('.menu ul')` and add 'active 'class to `$(".menu").parents("li")` you should do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Navigtion Stuff */
    
    $('.menu ul').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        },
        function(){
            $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
        }
    );
    $(".menu").parents("li").addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: cool, however missing the 'function() { ... }' part around the func body

Answer (score 2):

The ready function only takes one function as a parameter. See the above posts for examples.